# How to serve a Heroku app with Google cloud fixed IP

Tags: heroku, google-cloud-platform, dns, ip

I have a Heroku app that uses nodejs to serve a static web page https://foda-app.herokuapp.com

Heroku does not provide a fixed IP and I really need one for a personal project, so I'm trying to use Google Cloud's VPC reserved static external IP addresses.

I was able to reserve the IP but I'm not sure how should I link it with my Heroku app, since the Google Cloud offers so many options and services. I just wanna redirect all traffic from this IP to the Heroku app and I can't find a simple way to do it.

I need to create a global forwarding rule but I can't find a way to achieve this without using a lot of other services. Do I need a VM instance? Do I need a load balancer? Should I use VPC routes or Cloud DNS? I'm overwhelmed with all those services.

Please can someone tell me if it's possible, and what is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: using google cloud DNS update CNAME with herokuapp URL

Comment: I created a new DNS zone with google cloud DNS, now should I add a new CNAME record that points to the URL or to the heroku DNS? And what is the DNS name I should use?

Comment: Can you expand on why you "really need [a fixed IP] for a personal project"? Depending on your technical needs you may not be getting what you think you're getting using Google Cloud.

Comment: I'm trying to use the Handshake project Namespace new domains https://namebase.io/handshake-whitepaper/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using below two ways. -

1. Use a third party addon on heroku. eg. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quotaguardstatic
2. Setup a proxy server on the static IP, and redirect all traffic to the desired Heroku url.

Details for step 2 -

1. Assigning a static external IP address to a new VM instance https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address
2. Install Nginx/HAProxy on the newly procured VM.
3. setup config. like below -

   `upstream heroku-1{
           server foda-app.herokuapp.com fail_timeout=15s;
   }
   server{
       listen 80;
       server_name yourdomain.example or ip address
       location / {
           proxy_pass http://heroku-1;
           proxy_read_timeout 300;
       }
   }`
4. Change DNS mapping for your domain(if any) to point to the static IP.

Comment: Thanks @mdeora, since the heroku addon don't provide free service, could you please elaborate a little on how to setup a proxy server on google cloud static IP?

Comment: For setting up a proxy server, you need to take a cloud instance map the static ip to it, and install any proxy server, eg. Nginx or HAProxy and set your heroku app as the backend for the proxy server.

Comment: I'll try that out but seems like a over the top to install a proxy server on a instance just to redirect traffic. If you explain how this is done with a few more details I'll give you the reward.

Comment: added more details.

Comment: Thanks. I created the VM and after some package installs (dbus and systemctl) and I used nano to include your suggestion to nginx.conf (I've used my domain foda.app) but I got an error: `nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: You need to debug what exactly is the error. Look in the error log file /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: I got everything working as you said (nginx status is active and running with no errors) but the IP isn't working. I can see the nginx welcome screen on http but no redirect and no https. Can you point me towards a solution?

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ - It seems the reverse proxy is not setup correctly.

Comment: https://websiteforstudents.com/setup-nginx-reverse-proxy-apache2-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/

Comment: I ended up editing the default nginx html to redirect and I learned that to serve https properly I need custom credentials (and I don't want no credentials). Anyway, the fixed IP is working now, thanks for your help.